# Compare two files using awk having many columns and get the column in which data is different

Tags: bash, unix, awk, compare

file 1:

```
field1|field2|field3|
abc|123|234
def|345|456
hij|567|678
```

file2:

```
field1|field2|field3|
abc|890|234
hij|567|658
```

desired output:

```
field1|field2|field3|
abc|N|Y
def|345|456
hij|Y|N
```

I need to compare.if the fields match , then it shld put Y , else N in the output file.

Comment: Why is the def row with numbers instead of Y or N, in your desired output?

Comment: yes i just want to highlight the different in columns

Comment: But why is it wrong? Is it a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`, you may try this:

```
awk -F '|' 'FNR == NR {
   p = $1
   sub(p, "")
   a[p] = $0
   next
}
{
   if (FNR > 1 && $1 in a) {
      split(a[$1], b, /\|/)
      printf "%s", $1 FS
      for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
         printf "%s%s", ($i == b[i] ? "Y" : "N"), (i == NF ? ORS : FS)
   }
   else
      print
}' file2 file1
```

```
field1|field2|field3|
abc|N|Y
def|345|456
hij|Y|N
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/EyrAcP)

Comment: this is not giving the desired output.It ouptuts           field1|field2|field3|
abc|123|234
def|345|456
hij|Y|N

Comment: Hi Anubhava , i m very new with awk...can u help me to clear how it is working.Thanks